# Nativescript - accessing native platform api

Tags: nativescript

I followed the instructions at this link [Native APIs via TypeScript](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/accessing-native-apis-with-javascript)

As soon as I install the declarations plug-in, change references and tsconfig file - I'm getting errors for all my require statements.

`import observable = require( "data/observable" );
import frameModule = require("ui/frame");`

The error is "Cannot find module..."

Comment: Run a build for your app and restart your IDE.

Comment: Thanks that worked - but had to upgrade to typescript 2.1.5.

Comment: as a side note.. in order to be as ES6 compatible as possible it is better practice to use `import * as xModule from "xModule"` instead of `import xModule = require("xModule")`